# Add Lando to git bash profile

Tags: cmd, git-bash, lando

In cmd I am able to call `lando` but not in gitbash.

I know the executable is C:\Program Files\Lando\bin\lando.exe

Answer (score 0):

in gitbash

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Lando/bin"
```

Close out of git bash and reopen.